# Removing bolding within moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I write my CV with [moderncv](https://launchpad.net/moderncv) and `\moderncvstyle{casual}`.
`\cvitemwithcomment` writes the first column without bolding but the second one bolded. How can I remove the bolding from it?

Comment: A minimal example would be nice

Comment: you don't mean `\cventry`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you gave no MWE (please give us a MWE for your next question!), we can only guess.

I guess you are using an older version of `moderncv`, because with the current version 2.0.0   that does not happen.  You can check this with compiling the example file of `moderncv`.   See Languages, there is `\cvitemwithcomment` used.

I changed the part of Languages to the follwing code:

```
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment} % unchanged ==========
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment} % changed ==========
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment} % unchanged ==========
```

Have a look to the following result:

[image: Languages skills with changed code]

As you can see, Language 1 has no bold typing, but Language 2 has it caused by `\textbf` in the code.

Please check the version of `moderncv` you have installed, update and check your code to **not** use `\textbf` or similar inside. Then you will get the wanted result.

Here a compilable, shortend example file for `moderncv` with my changes:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment} % unchanged ==========
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment} % changed ==========
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment} % unchanged ==========

\end{document}
```